# Command to paste the Clipboard content into Notepad

Tags: windows, command-line, command

I have scenario where I can use only command line operations to do my things.

I have some file which is already opened. I want to copy the content from this file and save it to notepad.

I am able to do CTRL+A, CTRL+C, now since this is now in clipboard.

Do we have any one line command by which I can paste this clipboard content directly to a notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for various CLIP tools that can write from the clipboard into a file.

A batch file can help you utilise them...